How to create array in LO basic with support VBA 1
i have a code
Const maxPump As Byte = 3

Public ArrPump(1 to maxPump) As TPump

it work until i write
Option VbaSupport 1

after i got error like this
basic error '9' index out of defined range
i use libreoffice basic. How i can solve this problem?
my type of TPump
Type TPump
    Run As Boolean
    Err As Boolean
    Time As Integer
End Type

i wrote this code

Public ArrPump() As TPump

Sub initArr()
ReDim Preserve ArrPump(3)
ArrPump(1).Run = True
ArrPump(1).Err = False
ArrPump(1).Time = 10
ArrPump(2).Run = False
ArrPump(2).Err = True
ArrPump(2).Time = 20
ArrPump(3).Run = True
ArrPump(3).Err = False
ArrPump(3).Time = 30
End Sub

but when i using this code   If ArrPump(i).Run Then after init array i got error
basic error '9' index out of defined range
https://dropmefiles.com/27ShZ link on LO file

What's the value of i when the error occurs?

when i initArr ArrPump length is 4
but when i click button that change ArrPump(1),Run = True  then throw error, and length is 0

Your code works for me.

okay i will add more code

i was add link https://dropmefiles.com/27ShZ on my LO file

First of all, 9 is not the index. Rather, it is an identifier of the error message that is described in text as "Index out of defined range." It's just a coincidence that your initArr() happens to have 9 lines.
Now, the following code is fine.
initArr
MsgBox "Array size is " & LBound(ArrPump) & " to " & UBound(ArrPump)
i = 1
If ArrPump(i).Run Then
    MsgBox("OK")
End If

However, if we comment out the line that calls initArr, then it shows Array size is 0 to -1 and produces the error message shown in the post. So it looks like the problem in your spreadsheet is that initArr never gets called.
P.S. I looked at the file you uploaded, although on this site that's not normally how things are done because all necessary information should be included in the post. Anyway, the code has Start() and StartProgram() that would call initArr, but it isn't clear when you plan to call them. Maybe you wanted to include those in Doc_open, which is set up to get called from the document opening event.

i call StartProgram (inside init array) that call NextRun then start timer, it repeat Doc_Open (inside call loopWork) and after all i click on button "Ошибка" and got error
if you click on first button with this name  you will get msgbox with length of arrPump is 0 but why ? if firstly time i call StartProgram() (inside calling initArr) then i click button and arrPump length is 0 if before i run initArr and length is 4

and i need initArr only one time while running program cuz it saving state

saving state — Are you trying to save the array across macro calls? If so, use Global instead of Public. Note that modifying the code will lose the state. In general, saving state like this is not great — better to save the values persistently in the spreadsheet or document properties for example.

Maybe the real problem here is Option VbaSupport 1. I strongly recommend removing that. It should only be used when you need a particular kind of object and there's no way to do something similar in standard LibreOffice Basic. Otherwise, you're inviting all kinds of new potential errors and confusion, as we've seen here today. Even with that option, it will not actually be VBA in MS Office.

without option VbaSupport 1 doesnt work Application.OnTime
I think I have figured it out, probably, it is an issue with this line:
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "Standard.Module1.Doc_open
It calls the function loopWork() not from the same context, but as a new script so it's not in our scope. How can I make it call our function directly?

change public on global doesnt help

You're right, Application.OnTime is one of the few good reasons to use option VbaSupport. Anyway, I suggest you open a new question now that we've determined why the error occurs and how to fix it, which is the topic of this post. The new topic should be how to use Application.OnTime to call a routine that needs to remember a value between calls. Also, a lot of people (such as I) use python for these types of threading tasks — mention in the new post whether that would be acceptable or not for your project.

thank you. your comment helped me solve the problem. Now I storing the information from the arrays in cells. Could you please write your previous comment as a response so that I can mark it as the correct answer? @jim-k

It would be better for you to post an answer so that others can easily read it later. Include the relevant parts of your working code, along with an explanation of the problem and the solution. Quote the parts of my comments that helped you find the solution. Note that you may need to wait a few days until you're allowed to accept your own answer, but please remember to do so.
